# how to execute query for Memcached Buckets

Tags: node.js, couchbase

As I know I can use view to execute query for couchbase buckets

such as

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc.type && doc.type == "beer" && doc.name) {    
     emit(doc.name, null);
  }
}
```

but there is no option in Memcached Buckets

[image]

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcache buckets does not support persistence. Views are in fact materialized index, stored on the disk. So everything is correct on your screenshots: it is not possible to query memory-only buckets.

Comment: does this mean that if I hope to query, it is best to put list/array in couchbase rather than memcache? Is memcache better for storing variants rather than list/array? Is there big performance difference for the two mode?